# How to insert all values after create table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have created a table "test" after that added column "score" and "id"
I try to add various id instead of null so how can I add id?

Comment: Does the `id` have to be a specific value, or can you just use an auto-incrementing number?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)  and also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` so we know what you are talking about..

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want increasing number in a column, do a try:

```
//execute 
SET @val := 0;

//update 
UPDATE test SET id = ( SELECT @val := @val + 1 ) ORDER BY id;
```

Probably you will get an error of `safe updates`, run this command and retry:

```
set sql_safe_updates = 0;
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland primafacie it looks like. Lets OP to confirm.

Comment: i more meant this is big thumb guessing , we all don't know what the topicstarter is trying to do anyhow..

Comment: flipping a coin, it landed on head, so i will pass guessing  :-)